# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'connectNative' in Native Messaging App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-apps, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I am working on native messaging app.I have created following files

1.C++ conole app
2.JS file
3. manifet file
I have created registry entry like this [image]

Now I am getting error in the line **port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);**.I noticed chrome.runtime itself is undefined.let me know am I missing anything here.

**Manifest.jason**

```
function connect() {
  //var m1 = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
  var hostName = "NM1";
  var t1 = chrome;
  appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")    

  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
  updateUiState();
}
```

**main.js**

```
function connect() {
  //var m1 = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
  var hostName = "NM1";  
  appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")

  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
  updateUiState();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you accidentally copied in main.js twice, instead of copying in your manifest.json.

Answer (score 5):

You will probably get this error if you aren't running the javascript within your extension.  The chrome runtime doesn't exist outside that, and if you are running the javascript via injection, the runtime doesn't exist there.

Furthermore, don't forget to include the **nativeMessaging** permission in the manifest.json.

```
"permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
]
```